# MAMP MySQL Server not starting

Tags: mysql, innodb, mamp

Trying to use MAMP's MySQL on a windows laptop but it won't start, checked logs and keep getting this. any  suggestions on how to fix?

```
161113 21:20:28 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
161113 21:20:28 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
161113 21:20:28 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
161113 21:20:28  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
161113 21:20:28 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
161113 21:20:28 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
161113 21:20:28 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
161113 21:20:28 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: What do you mean by "MAMP's MySQL"? If "MAMP" refers to the infamous "Mac, Apache, MySQL, PHP", then certainly that MySQL version will _not_ be usable on a MS-Windows based system...

Comment: https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/ . there is a windows version